# How to get rectangular inclination from axis-aligned bounding box?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, transform, transformation

My binary image has rectangular rotated objects of known size on it. I'd like to get the object inclination using axis-aligned bounding box that MATLAB's regionprops returns. What are my suggestions:

Let bounding box width be W, side of rectangle be C and inclination alpha

Then

[image]

Using Weierstrass substitution

[image]

After some simplification:

[image]

Solving the equation for tan(alpha/2) with [image]

[image]

For any nonzero inclination discriminant is positive.

[image]

Logic seems to be OK, so as math. Could you please point where I make a mistake, or what is a better way to get inclination?

Here is corresponding MATLAB code:

```
img = false(25,25);
img(5:16,5:16) = true;
rot_img = imrotate(img, 30, 'crop');
props = regionprops(bwlabel(rot_img),'BoundingBox');
bbox = cat(1,props.BoundingBox);
w = bbox(3);
h = 12;
a = -1*(1+w/h); b = 2; c = 1 - w/h;
D = b^2 - 4*a*c;
alpha = 2*atand((-b + sqrt(D))/(2*a));
%alpha = 25.5288
```

EDIT Thank you for trigonometry hints. They significantly simplify the calculations, but they give wrong answer. As I now understand, the question is asked in wrong way. The thing I really need is finding inclination of short lines (10-50 pixels) with high accuracy (+/- 0.5 deg), the lines' position is out of interest.

The approach used in the question and answers show better accuracy for long lines, for c = 100 error is less than 0.1 degree. That means we're into rasterization error here, and need subpixel accuracy. At the moment I have only one algorithm that solves the problem - Radon transform, but I hope you can recommend something else.

```
p = bwperim(rot_img);
theta=0:0.1:179.9;
[R,xp] = radon(p,theta); %Radon transform of contours
a=imregionalmax(R,true(3,3)); %Regional maxima of the transform
[r,c]=find(a); idx=sub2ind(size(a),r,c); maxvals=R(idx);
[val,midx]=sort(maxvals,'descend'); %Choose 4 highest maxima
mean(rem(theta(c(midx(1:4))),90)) %And average corresponding angles
%29.85
```

Answer (score 1):

If rectangle is square:

```
w/c=sin(a)+cos(a)
(w/c)^2=1+sin(2a)
sin(2a)=(w/c)^2-1
a=0.5*arcsin((w/c)^2-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be use regionprops function with 'Orientation' option...

Comment: I tried it, but answer is still not right, for the example above it is -23.0850.